# Maximize an integral

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

I have the following integral to maximize but I don't know what to do with this $f(b,y)$ in the first integrand:

$$
F=\intop_{a}^{b}[f(b,y)+\intop_{a}^{b}f(x,y)dx]dy
$$
*a* and *b* are constants.
Do I treat $f(b,y)$ as a separate function? Thanks!

UPD A more useful expression of the same problem would be the following:
$$
F=\intop_{a}^{b}\intop_{a}^{b}[G(f(x,y),y)+H(f(b,y),y)]dxdy
$$

Comment: You can write the integral as $\int_{a}^b\int_{a}^b \left[\frac{f(b,y)}{b-a}+f(x,y)\right]dx\ dy$ then maybe you can apply Euler-Lagrange theorem on the integral inside.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f(b,y)}{\partial f(x,y)}$ then?

Comment: It means the Jacobian matrix of the function $f(b,y)$ i.e. imagine putting $x=b$ in there. That is it becomes contant in the $x$ direction and hence the derivative vanishes.

Comment: @dcs24 please see the update. Do you mean the EL condition writes as $G_{f}|_{x\neq b}=0,G_{f}|_{x=b}=-H_{f}$?

Comment: I cannot elaborate fully at present. I will try to reply this evening (UK).